# Implementing a collection using another collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Often you have to implement a collection because it is not present among those of the .NET Framework. In the examples that I find online, often the new collection is built based on another collection (for example, `List<T>`): in this way it is possible to avoid the management of the resizing of the collection.

```
public class CustomCollection<T>
{
    private List<T> _baseArray;

    ...

    public CustomCollection(...)
    {
        this._baseArray = new List<T>(...);
    }
}
```

1. What are the disadvantages of following this approach? Only lower performance because of the method calls to the base collection? Or the compiler performs some optimization?
2. Moreover, in some cases the field relating to the base collection (for example the above `_baseArray`) is declared as `readonly`. Why?

Comment: I don't understand this: "in this way it is possible to avoid the management of the resizing of the collection" in the context of your overall question.

Comment: @Joe: I think he's referring to using a list instead of a plain array.

Comment: @Joe: In order to resize a plain array, I have to create another array of the new size and copy the elements to the new array, then destroy the old array... If I use a List, these operations are transparent.

Comment: I didn't see anything mentioning arrays in the original question.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by implementing a custom collection?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I implemented a binary heap, so I have at least the `Insert` and `Remove` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The main disadvantage is the fact that if you want to play nice you'll have to implement a lot of interfaces by hand (ICollection, IEnumerable, possibly IList... both generic and non-generic), and that's quite a bit of code. Not complex code, since you're just relaying the calls, but still code. The extra call to the inner list shouldn't make too big of a difference in most cases.
2. It's to enforce the fact that once the inner list is set, it cannot be changed into another list.

Usually it's best to inherit from one of the many built-in collection classes to make your own collection, instead of doing it the hard way. `Collection<T>` is a good starting point, and nobody is stopping you from inheriting `List<T>` itself.

Comment: don't inherit from `List<T>` - its methods are not declared virtual, so that is a no-go

Comment: @BrokenGlass: It's not a no-go if you don't need to override any of them. Sometimes it's useful to have a collection with the exact functionality of a list, plus a few methods. Of course if you need to change the functionality of the build-in methods, `Collection<T>` is the class to use.

Comment: That's not exactly what `readonly` means. You *can* set it multiple times, but only from constructor or field initializer.

Comment: @svick: Unless we define "once it's set" as when all the constructors and field initializers have been run!

Answer (score 2):

For #2: if the private member is only assigned to in the constructor or when declared, it can be `readonly`.  This is usually true if you only have one underlying collection and don't ever need to recreate it.

Comment: So, if I recreate the list by mistake in some method/property, the compiler reports the error: an additional form of security from this type of error?

Comment: Yes, though I don't usually think of it as a security issue as much as a design issue.  I don't *expect* the collection to ever be replaced, so I enforce it with `readonly`.  There would be some uses where you wouldn't want this (e.g. a large-scale refresh, that replaces the old collection with a new one after loading from an external source...)

Answer (score -1):

I'd say a pretty large disadvantage of this approach is that you can't use LINQ on your custom collection unless you implement `IEnumerable`. A better approach might be to subclass and force new implementation on methods as necessary, ex:

```
public class FooList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        // any FooList-specific logic regarding adding items
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

As for the `readonly` keyword, it means that you can only set the variable in the constructor.

Comment: It's a bad idea to inherit from `List<T>` - your example shows why - the base methods are not virtual so all you are doing is hiding the base class methods which is not a robust solution at all.